# Analog Multiplier

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog

I designed an analog multiplier made of op amps but it didnt work, so I found a pic where they added another op amp and its working now.
Im not sure what the purpose of this amp and how it's helping to get the right answer at the output.
V6, V7 are the inputs I want to multiply.
[image]

Thanks for your help. (it's my first post here)

Comment: What is the voltage at the output of U9C?

Comment: Now it's 552mV.
Btw if i put there -2 volt it devides the output by 2.

Comment: "*... but it didn't work*" isn't a very good technical description of the problem. What result did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit calculates (V7 * V6)/1

The division by 1 is caused by the -1V of V5.

The reason for needing to divide by 1 is to reduce the output voltage at the output of the adder so that the input to the anti-log amp is in the correct voltage range to be converted back to a meaningful result.

Without the division by 1, the voltage at the output of the adder would be too large (not to the same scale that the log amps are working on) to be converted back to a meaningful result.

Comment: Thanks that's a great answer! Do you know why it divides the output by -V5? By adding this amp, it's like adding -log(1) in the input of the adder?

Comment: @LiorD When multiplying two numbers, take the logs, add and then antilog. When dividing two numbers, take the logs, subtract and then antilog. The adder, because it is inverting, is subtracting log(1) (the log amp is also inverting). - hence an overall division by 1. There are then two further inversions, the anti-log amp and the final inverter. So 4 inversions in all yielding the correct output polarity.

Comment: @LiorD You may be able to achieve better output accuracy by using op amps with lower input bias currents.

Comment: @LiorD It is important to appreciate that the voltages at the outputs of the log amps are not actually the log values of the input voltages, it's just that, because of the logarithmic diode characteristic, these outputs vary in a logarithmic fashion in relation to the input voltages (or currents if you wish). This means that, when put through the reverse process of "anti-logging", the correct voltage appears at the output of the circuit.